# How to override hover event to click event for CSS dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am attempting to create a pure CSS multi-level dropdown menu. I got it to work for hovering.  However, I only want it to hover in the submenu, but the main menu item to be clickable to expand the menu.  I tried to add jquery to override the hovering to clickable action, but it's not working.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<nav class="nav">
```

Home

```
<li class="menu-item subItem"><a href="">Menu1<b class="down-arrow"></b></a>      
  <ul class="submenu">
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Menu Item 1</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item subItem"><a href="">Submenu <b class="right-arrow"></b></span></a>
      <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Sub1</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Sub2</a></li>

      <li class="menu-item subItem"><a href="">3rd Level <b class="right-arrow"></b></span></a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Level1</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Level2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

```
<script>
$(function() {     
$('.menu-item').on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.submenu').show();
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: If you make the menu to react to a `hover` event with CSS, the JavaScript `e.preventDefault()` doesn't override it.

Comment: It would be useful if you create a snippet with the minimum amount of CSS necessary to make it work. Also, you should expand the "it's not working thing". Read the ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and, especially, about creating a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Css would be helpful. Try throwing an `$('.menu-item').hover(function(){});` in there to override the existing function. Or, find and remove it from the existing script.